# Stop being auto-subscribed to GitHub repositories from an organisation

Tags: github, notifications

I’ve been joined to a GitHub “organisation” for some things I do at the day job occasionally (administrative and Debian packaging things). I’m not normally involved in the development of the stuff hosted by that GitHub organisation.

However, when someone creates a new repository on that organisation, I am automatically subscribed to it and need to manually unwatch it, *all the time*.

How can I stop being automatically subscribed to new repositories—ideally, for one particular organisation only?

Comment: Unfortunately (and rather infuriatingly), this is [not possible for a single organisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108169/how-do-i-turn-off-automatic-notification-subscription-for-new-repositories-in-a)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Go to [GitHub settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications)

You'll see this:

> **Automatic Watching**
>
> **☑ Automatically watch repositoiries**
>
> When you’re given push access to a repository, automatically receive notifications for it.

If you uncheck or untick that box you should now have to manually watch repositories that are added by your joined organisation if they've also given you push access.

You can't set it on a per organisation level though. It's all or nothing at the moment.

Comment: This has moved into the settings/notifs page: https://github.com/settings/notifications

Answer (score 0):

Go to [github.com/settings/notifications](https://github.com/settings/notifications) and uncheck "Automatically watch repositories" under "Automatic Watching".

Comment: Hi there! While true, this answer is identical to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/62832/72101 with the update from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62472/stop-being-auto-subscribed-to-github-repositories-from-an-organisation/126941#comment67910_62832 so it’s redundant and could be removed.